# How to use prepareForDeletion to delete photo in CoreData swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I tired to solve this issue but when it remove it remove other photo path because i use .lastPathComponent[image]

```
   override func prepareForDeletion() {

    super.prepareForDeletion()
    if filePath != nil {

        let fileName = (filePath! as NSString).lastPathComponent

        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentationDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

        let pathArray = [dirPath, fileName]

        let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)!

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(fileURL)
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(fileName)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error from prepareForDeletion - \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("filepath is empty")
    }
}
```

I got it

the correct filePath detected 
that is the correct answer

```
 override func prepareForDeletion() {
   super.prepareForDeletion()

   if filePath != nil {

   if let imagePath = self.filePath {

     do {
         try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(imagePath)
     } catch let error as NSError {
         print("Error from prepareForDeletion - \(error)")
     }
   }
 } else {
print("filepath is empty")
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you having two "remove" statements in the "do" statement? Please remove the line

```
try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(fileName
```

and check if the error still exists.

Comment: i remove it 
i was added when i was try to get answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't save file path to database, only save filename to database then create path in function for delete. try this method.

```
override func prepareForDeletion() {

        super.prepareForDeletion()
        if filename != nil {
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentationDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

        let pathArray = [dirPath, filename]

        let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)!

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(fileURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error from prepareForDeletion - \(error)")
        }
        } else {
              print("filepath is empty")
        }
```

}

Comment: it is filePath how to do it

Comment: filePath it is a property from class Photo

Comment: file path should not be store in database. what you have to do is, save filename to filePath property. as you are not planing to change property name. then call shared function

Comment: i found the answer for this issue it summarized in get filePAth and detect it